# add a column of zeros to a new text file with bash

Tags: bash

This is probably super easy but I can't seem to find an answer.
I would like to create a new .txt file in a bash script and add a new column of zeros (repeating 180 times).

```
new_dir=/Users/Desktop/
touch $new_dir/newfile.txt
echo "0 "*180 >> $new_dir/newfile.txt
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Repeat line with `yes`, get 180 lines with `head`:

```
yes 0 | head -n180 > file
```

Comment: This seems to work! Thanks


`new_dir=/Users/Desktop/`

`touch $new_dir/newfile.txt`

`yes 0 | head -n180 > $new_dir/newfile.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following. Considering that you need 180 new lines of zeros here.

```
awk 'BEGIN{while(++i<=180){print "0"}}' > "$new_dir/newfile.txt"
```

***Explanation:***

```
awk '                         ##Starting awk program.
BEGIN{                        ##Starting BEGIN section of awk which will NOT need any Input_file to read.
  while(++i<=180){            ##Starting a while loop which runs from i=1 to till i=180
    print "0"                 ##Printing 0 here.
  }                           ##Closing while loop BLOCK here.
}                             ##Closing BEGIN section of this program here.
' > "$new_dir/newfile.txt"    ##Redirecting output to output file here.
```

---

---

In case you want to add zero 180 in a single row then try following:

```
awk 'BEGIN{printf("%0180d\n",0)}' > "$new_dir/newfile.txt"
```

Comment: is this the way I should include the output dir?
`awk 'BEGIN{while(++i<=180){print "0" > "$new_dir/newfile.txt"}}' `

it gives an error:
Command 'b'new_dir=/Users/ilkay.isik/Desktop/\ntouch $new_dir/newfile.txt\nawk \'BEGIN{while(++i<=180){print "0" > "$new_dir/newfile.txt"}}\' \n'' returned non-zero exit status 2.

Comment: @IlkayIsik, You could do like this `awk 'BEGIN{while(++i<=180){print "0"}}' > "$new_dir/newfile.txt"` and lemme know in case of any queries.

Comment: @IlkayIsik, Since `awk` is a separate language itself so to call shell variables inside `awk` is a different proedure, hence I called your shell variables outside of `awk` command in Input_file mentioning place.

Answer (score 1):

A new column on a new file would mean you are just creating a new file with 180 zeroes separated by newlines. Just FYI, this is different from (and simpler than) adding a new column to a file with pre-existing data.

Anyway, there are many ways to do this. If you want to do it via simply programming functions, you can always wrap your echo with a loop:

```
for i in {1..180}
do
    echo "0 " >> $new_dir/newfile.txt
done
```

Alternatively, there are a lot of more "creative" methods like using `awk` or other tools.

Comment: thanks for the clear answer. when I googled I always found the examples for adding a new column to a file with pre-existing data, I guessed that what I am asking for is simpler but could not come up with the solution

Answer (score 0):

Like this with only shell builtins :

```
printf '%.0q0\n' {1..180} > output_file
```